# WikiJs GraphQl select content type when creating a page

Tags: graphql

Hello I am currently having the problem that if I try to create a page with the GraphQl Api for WikiJs that the content type is always text when I would like it to be markdown. Does someone know what I a doing wrong or what I need to change in my query. Below you find an exmaple of the query used.

```
mutation{
      pages{
          create(content: "Test for best result", description: "Testsite to check creation", editor: "Markdown", isPublished: true, isPrivate: false, locale : "en", path: "/home/product_factory/devops/monitoring/Changelogs/", title: "New Changelog", tags: [])

          {
            responseResult
            {
                succeeded
                errorCode
            }
          }
      }
}
```

I tried searching online for  a solution but found nothing. I also tried creating a page in the web ui and there everthing works.

Comment: Have found the error markdown must be not be capitalized. Using Markdown throws no error but the content type is set to text. Using markdown leads to the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found the error markdown must not be capitalized. Using Markdown throws no error but the content type is set to text. Using markdown leads to the correct result.

Comment: I don't see this in the official documentation: https://docs.requarks.io/en/dev/api
Not sure of the official process for updating it, but consider using the "Report a Bug" feature on that page.